# Why won't this JS RegExp work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of YouTube videos on a page and I want to use JS to grab a list of the src URLs from each `<embed>` tag and use them to append thumbnail images elsewhere on the page.

To do this, I need to grab the Video ID from the YouTube URL using a RegExp, but it refuses to work, even though the RegExp appears to work when I test it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Here's the code I have:

**Here is the JSBin page to see it all in action: http://jsbin.com/uvoya3/23/edit

```
var addImages = function () {
  var features = document.getElementById('features'),
  embeds = features.getElementsByTagName('embed'),
  ids = [], i, thumbNav, items, mysrc, pattern, ytid, newImg, matchArray;

  for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i += 1) {
    mysrc = embeds[i].getAttribute('src');
    pattern = /^(http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\?[^\?]*)$/;
    ytid = mysrc.replace(pattern, '$2');

    alert("src number " + i + " is " + ytid);
    ids.push(ytid);
  }

};

window.onload = addImages;
```

The alert is there to test what the RegExp is finding, and each time it pushes the whole mysrc string because it's not matching at all. The mysrc values are

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/jfiNQGFVjb4?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US
http://www.youtube.com/v/qtzjzMsJiO8?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US
http://www.youtube.com/v/baa-dGj2LhQ?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US
```

which are being pulled from this HTML

```
<ul id="features">
  <li><object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/jfiNQGFVjb4?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/jfiNQGFVjb4?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object></li>
  <li><object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/qtzjzMsJiO8?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/qtzjzMsJiO8?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object></li>
  <li><object width="640" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/baa-dGj2LhQ?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/baa-dGj2LhQ?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="385"></embed></object></li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone see why my RegExp or my JS is off track here?

**PS Here is the JSBin URL http://jsbin.com/uvoya3/23/edit

Comment: It seems to be working pretty well as far as I can tell, though you need to make sure that the "src" name can contain a dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine, except for the third one, because that one contains a `-`. And by the way, `_` may be supported as well.

So, a better regular expression would be: `/^(http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)(\?[^\?]*)$/`.

On my Javascript console this works fine:

```
> "http://www.youtube.com/v/baa-dGj2LhQ?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US".replace(/^(http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)(\?[^\?]*)$/, '$2');
< "baa-dGj2LhQ"
```

---

You could optimize your code by the way:

```
var addImages = function () {

  // Part 1
  var features = document.getElementById('features'),
  embeds = features.getElementsByTagName('embed'),
  pattern = /^(http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)(\?[^\?]*)$/,
  ids = [], i, thumbNav, items, mysrc, ytid, newImg;

  for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
    ids[i] = embeds[i].src.replace(pattern, '$2');
  }

  ...
```